# How to fix nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed

Tags: react-native

When I run my application i'm getting this error after a successful build .

> nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed: dlopen(/usr/lib/libquic.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Users/cmrah/Projects/nova/packages/tv/ios/DerivedData/tf1/Build/Products/Debug-appletvsimulator/libquic.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/tvOS_20L494/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/tvOS 16.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection/libquic.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/tvOS_20L494/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/tvOS 16.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libquic.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libquic.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

My emulator is an Apple TV 16.4

The application is launched on the emulator